# Нет доступа к Git-репозиторию после восстановления локальных файлов

Tags: git, github, git-push

Локальный проект, привязанный к Git, был удалён с ПК, а затем - восстановлен. После внесения изменений в код одного из файлов запрошены status и add ., затем успешный commit и push с ошибкой доступа к репозиторию:

[image: ошибка]

Пробовал pull по ссылке на репозиторий - не помогает.
Как мне можно вернуть доступ к репозиторию, не теряя предыдущие коммиты на GitHub?

Comment: *man git-remote*

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему:

- удаляем локальный репо, сделав копию актуальных файлов;
- снова делаем в папке "Git Bash Here", в консоли - git init (remote add не нужно - ветка и так уже есть);
- git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories (просто git pull origin master приводит к ошибке fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories);
- в репо появились последние файлы коммита, остальное добавляем из копии, сделанной ранее;
- git add .
- git commit -m "..."
- git push origin

Comment: `git clone` не проще?

Comment: Вместо `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` надо делать `git fetch origin matser && git checkout origin/master -B master`. Но проще сделать `git clone`.